# Map empty character literal as a return value

Tags: rust

I have simple piece of code. I want to remove non alphanumeric characters from a string. But i don't want to replace apostrophe with space i want to remove it. But that code doesn't compile saying it is illegal to return empty character literal. How can this be achived?

```rust
fn remove_non_chars(input: &str) -> String {
    input
        .chars()
        .map(|c| {
            if c.is_alphanumeric() || c.is_whitespace() {
                c
            } else if c == '\'' {
                ''
            } else {
                ' '
            }
        })
        .collect()
}
```

```
error: empty character literal
 --> src/lib.rs:9:18
  |
8 |                 ''
  |                  ^
```

Comment: `filter()` that very basic, `.filter(|c| c.is_alphanumeric() || c.is_whitespace())`, if you want you can use `filter_map` to replace with space

Comment: @Stargateur i updated code a little bit. `filter` will not do what i wan't because will get rid off apostrophe also.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1b7d008979d710f8104b07b15d8fb352

Comment: The reason why it's an error is because there is no such thing as an empty character literal. You're saying, return a 32-bit character and then out-of-the-blue saying, oh wait, this value won't even exist. You want `filter`/`filter_map`, not `map`.